# C# public interface vs interface

Tags: c#, interface, public

Is there any difference betwen public interface declaration and interface? (I thought that interfaces are public by default).

I am asking because VS2012 is whining about access levels.

I have declared:

```
interface Ixyz
{nothing important here}
```

and property (in another class who is using Ixhz as its type):

```
public Ixhz Somename
{nothing important here}
```

And when I try to compile the project, it whines about access levels but when I declare interface like `public interface Ixyz` it stops doing it. Are there any consequences of adding public to interface?

Comment: By default they are protected

Comment: look up `public` vs `internal`

Comment: @TomaszKowalczykL Wrong.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: No, they're really not. Top-level types are `internal` by default. Nested types are `private` by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Members* in interfaces are always public, and in fact cannot have access modifiers.

Interfaces themselves have the same default access level as other types.

Specifically, top-level types are `internal` by default, and nested types are `private` by default.